# How to install 7zip to extract rar files

Tags: software-installation, 7zip

How do I install 7zip through Terminal to extract rar files?

Answer (score 122):

I don't know why would you like specifically 7-zip's binary to extract RAR, but here we go:

To unrar files with... unrar:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar-free
unrar e some.rar
```

To extract rar files with 7-zip:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x some.rar
```

`e` and `x` mean extract obviously.

Comment: instead of using zip, tar, unrar, etc. we could use the same tool (7z) with the same interface for all of them

Answer (score 31):

You may use p7zip. And you can install p7Zip using command : `sudo apt-get install p7zip`.

To extract RAR archives, you'll need to install package "p7zip-rar", too.

Install it using : `sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar`

Or you can get it done in single command : `sudo apt-get install p7zip p7zip-rar`

Read p7zip manual for more information: `man p7zip`

Comment: Post-bounty note: This was the only answer that correctly mentioned the required package for 7zip to be able to extract rar files. `p7zip-rar` depends on `p7zip-full`, but the reverse is *not* true as assumed by other answers when bounty was started.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to Install 7Zip:

```
$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Extract files using 7zip:

```
$ 7z e example.zip
```

(Or use the `x` option instead of `e` to preserve file paths).

Compress files using 7zip:

```
$ 7z a compress.zip
```

For more information, visit the [reference](https://www.tecrobust.com/install-7zip-extractor-compressor-linux/)

Comment: I didn't come right with the accepted answer. This worked spot-on.