# Archiver/extracting similar to winrar?

Tags: rar

Basically, I have been looking for an archiver/extracter/whatever you call it that is as good as winrar. Multiple part support, password support, GUI interface, easy to navigate, and basically everything that makes Winrar so awesome. I know Winrar makes a command line tool for Linux, bug I am looking for a GUI thing. When I tried to install Winrar on PlayOnLinux, that didn't work either, I got an error when installing. So does anyone have an archiving tool for Linux that does everything Winrar does? (Note, the built in one does not have password support)

Comment: Which archiving tool is "the built in one"? I assume you mean file-roller, but it does have password support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have not found a program that runs natively on linux, but luckily I was able to get 7-zip installed via PlayOnLinux, and I now have a good archive manager! Not very fast, could have something to with wine/playonlinux, but the convenience is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PlayOnLinux and Wine, I would suggest you to use the excellent Bandizip archive manager : http://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/
It is a free (but not open source software) but it is the only solution I've found to open "rar" files on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I used ended up using 7zip on PlayOnLinux and it worked perfectly :). I like 7zip because it is pretty close to WinRAR, my favorite archiving program on windows, and since i could not get winrar working on PlayOnLinux, 7zip ended up working just fine :)

Comment: That's right, 7zip is a great software too...

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest checking out free [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). It has got a GUI and as far as I know it supports all the features you ask for including *.rar files.

You can install it from command line using `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348173/how-to-install-7zip-to-extract-rar-files/348176).

Comment: Well, that program does not have a GUI. I did check this program earlier on, but even on the website you liked, it said this: "p7zip is the **command line** version of 7-Zip for Linux / Unix, made by an independent developer." Also, when I tried this to extract a multi part rar, it gave the following message: "/usr/bin/p7zip: Downloads/FCRedmdt.part1.rar: unknown suffix -- ignored" So it seems like it does not support multi part rar either...