# extracting RAR files on Ubuntu 20.10,Ubuntu LTS also on Fedora 33 not working

Tags: archive, fedora, rar

I decided to leave Windows and jump in to the Linux, but when I install Ubuntu LTS 20.04 and want to extract RAR, with Archive Manager it stays in (Extracting files from "site.rar [86mg] ") please wait !!!
And nothing else. I try it on Fedora too!
asus-k55vd intel i5

Comment: in archive manager on top is : Read Only , why?

Comment: To enable full support for other major archive formats, [you must install a few extra apps](https://linuxhint.com/extract_compressed_archive/): `sudo apt install zip unzip rar unrar p7zip-full`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install 7zip to extract rar files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348173/how-to-install-7zip-to-extract-rar-files)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the *unrar* package:

```
sudo apt install unrar
```