# Help me..How can i install an tar.xz file

Tags: 22.04

I am a new Ubuntu user from Windows. I never downloaded 7zip for Linux; when I did, I had a tar.xz file. How do I make it become an application to run it? Also, if there is a way to install it via the terminal, can you show me what that is?
P.s If my spelling is not correct, sue the company who made Grammarly

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** [Please read this similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/92328/32664) to see if if resolves your issue.

Comment: What do you want to install? Most software can be installed from official repositories without downloading anything from the web.

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: 7zip is easily available from the Ubuntu repositories. Check your Ubuntu Software application. Much easier than downloading and mucking about with tarballs. We migrated away from those 20 years ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install 7zip to extract rar files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348173/how-to-install-7zip-to-extract-rar-files)

Answer (score 1):

To install 7zip in Ubuntu 22.04  and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install 7zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `man tar`. Use `file foo.tar.xz` to be sure it's not a HTML file. Use `tar tAvf foo.tar.xz` to see a contents list. To extract the files, first do `mkdir ~/src`. Then `cd ~/src; tar xAvf ../foo.tar.xz`.

Now read the upper-case named files (`less [A-Z]*`). Follow the instructions contained therein.

Comment: I seem to not understand. sorry for the bother but I'm only using Ubuntu for 3 days